# Using indexOf() twice fails to detect second character occurence

Tags: java, string, loops

I have a string, something like 9.555.555,00 and want to remove all the symbols and just keep the numbers, this is in String format.

I am using indexof to find the special characters and then a loop in order to skip the particular character when the loop gets to it so it doesnt append that character to the final string.

However, when doing this, the code seems to pick up the first occurence of the period sign but then indexOf() returns -1 the second time, even though there is another . in the string.

```
int dotIndex, commaIndex;

        dotIndex = tempBalance.indexOf('.');
        commaIndex = tempBalance.indexOf(',');

        for(int j = 0; j < tempBalance.length(); ++j){

            //System.out.println("Iteration: " + j + " ~ i @ : " + i);

            if(j == dotIndex){
                System.out.println("Current dot Index: " + dotIndex + " J: " + j + " : " + tempBalance);
                dotIndex = tempBalance.indexOf(j+1, '.');
                System.out.println("New dotIndex: " + dotIndex);
                continue;
            } else if(j == commaIndex){
                break;
            } else {

                tempString.append(tempBalance.charAt(j));
                //System.out.print("Found normal Number: " + tempBalance.substring(j, (j+1)));
            }
```

Output for system.out.println:

> Current dot Index: 1 J: 1 : 9.955.458,23
>   New dotIndex: -1

Comment: @radimpe  It seems `replace` should be `replaceAll`

Comment: @AndrewThompson. No, `replace()` will work fine. It also replaces all the occurrences. `replaceAll()` on contrary is used for replacing regex pattern.

Comment: @RohitJain  Thanks for the correction.  It seems I was wrong.  :P

Comment: `indexOf()` returns index of first occurrence

Comment: `tempBalance.replace(".","").replace(",","")` will work. However replaceAll (eg. `tempBalance.replaceAll(".","").replaceAll(",","")`) does not work and return a blank response. I could be 'faulted' for putting them as `String` when `char` would do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dotIndex = tempBalance.indexOf(j+1, '.');
```

Should instead be

```
dotIndex = tempBalance.indexOf('.', j+1);
```

But that is not the only problem. Once you have the `'.'` fixed. You still need to sort out parsing all the `','` out as well. Simply fixing the above will still only return `9955458` minus the `23`

Comment: Very true, however I dont really need the last values as they are cents and if i append them to the whole number they have their value changed.

Answer (score 2):

`tempBalance.indexOf(j+1, '.')` should be `tempBalance.indexOf('.', j+1)`.
See [Javadocs for `indexOf(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int,%20int%29).

Answer (score 2):

You should switch argument places in `indexOf`:

```
dotIndex = tempBalance.indexOf('.', j + 1);
```

First argument is the character to search, second is the index to start with.

Answer (score 1):

To remove non-digit characters, you can do-

```
public static String removeNonDigits(String input) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char c = input.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            result.append(c);
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Also, for formatting number you can use [NumberFormat](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) with Locale.

Answer (score 0):

```
want to remove all the symbols(.,) and just keep the numbers
```

Using regular expression:

```
String exprStr="9.555.555,00";
exprStr=exprStr.replaceAll("[.,]","");
System.out.println(exprStr);
```

Where **[.,]** is the regular expression identifying either **.** or **,**